# Are homeomorphisms required to be unique in the definition of a topological manifold?

Tags: manifolds, definition

This question is motivated by typical "introductory" texts on smooth manifolds, but as far as I can tell, it applies more generally to topological manifolds. Using John M. Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" as my source, a topological $n$-manifold is defined as a topological space $(M,\mathscr{T})$ such that

1. $(M,\mathscr{T})$ is Hausdorff.
2. $(M,\mathscr{T})$ is second-countable.
3. $(M,\mathscr{T})$ is locally homeomorphic to Euclidean $n$-space: For any point $p \in M$ there exists a neighbourhood $U \in \mathscr{T}$, an open set $\widetilde{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and a homeomorphism $\varphi\colon U\to\widetilde{U}$ connecting the two. The function $\varphi$ is known as a ***coordinate map***.

With this setup, my question can be stated in several equivalent ways:

a) Do coordinate maps uniquely define a manifold? That is, if we change *one* coordinate map, say from $\varphi$ to $\varphi+\text{constant}$, will we obtain a different manifold than the one we started with?

b) Would a more pedantic writing of property 3 above be that to any point $p\in M$ and open sets $U\in\mathscr{T}, \widetilde{U}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ there must exist **at least one** homeomorphism $\varphi\colon U\to \widetilde{U}$?

From my experience in physics, I suspect that coordinate maps are not required to be unique—as far as I can tell, the "local likeness" to Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the important part when working with manifolds, not the exact coordinates we use—but I could not find a clear confirmation of this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your point number 3 should say "is LOCALLY homeomorphic to..." As for your questions (a) and (b), in math when we say "there exists..." we mean "there exists atleast one" (if we want to be more specific we would write "there exists a unique" or "there exist exactly 7..."). In fact in this case, if you can find one homeomorphism $\phi:U\to\tilde{U}$, you can find (uncountably) infinitely many other homeomorphisms from $U$ to (some other) open set $V\subset \Bbb{R}^n$

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Doh! Yes, you are obviously correct! Stupid question on my part, it seems!

Comment: I think this is reasonable, because once you start studying smooth manifolds you may have this (or a similar) question again. The way definitions are presented vary slightly among authors, but roughly, a smooth manifold is the data $(M,\mathscr{T},\mathcal{A})$, where $(M,\mathscr{T})$ is a topological manifold, and $\mathcal{A}$ is a maximal smooth atlas (some authors use the definition as an equivalence class of smooth atlases). If we modify the maximal atlas $\mathcal{A}$ to a different one $\mathcal{A}'$, then we consider them different manifolds even if the underlying set $M$ is the same.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Yes, to me it seems that topological manifolds could be defined as a tuple $(M,\mathscr{T},\mathcal{A})$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is simply a maximal (not necessarily smooth) atlas. Would this be correct?

Comment: yes (though I'd be more careful with the wording). The point is that if $(M,\mathscr{T})$ satisfies the definition of a topological manifold as above, then there certainly exists a maximal continuous atlas $\mathcal{A}$. But in fact this $\mathcal{A}$ is unique because a maximal continuous atlas is nothing but the set of all possible charts $(U,\phi)$, where $\phi:U\to \phi[U]\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism (the chart transition condition $\phi\circ \psi^{-1}$ being a homeo is automatically satisfied).

Comment: Conversely, if $(M,\mathscr{T})$ is a Hausdorff, second countable topological space and $\mathcal{A}$ is a maximal continuous atlas, then trivially, by definition of "continuous atlas", it follows that the pair $(M,\mathscr{T})$ satisfies (3) in the definition of topological manifold. So, because of the uniqueness of maximal continuous atlas $\mathcal{A}$, these two definitions are equivalent (but in the smooth setting, it is possible to have more than one maximal smooth atlas, so the $\mathcal{A}$ really is an additional piece of information)

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Gottcha. That explains why $\mathcal{A}$ is normally not drawn attention to when defining topological manifolds. Thanks!